# Alation Query form and parameter fails to pass multiple values

Tags: sql, alation

PLEASE NOTE There is another post from a few years back on this issue, but none of the responses solve this problem.

The goal is to create an Alation SQL form that allows for the user to enter multiple comma separated keywords.

The Alation guide seems to indicate that we should be able to pass multiple values, but not how. For example, do they need to be comma separated, separated by | etc.?  I have tried every combination I can think of and no records return when more than one keyword is entered.

The guide is located at https://docs2.alationdata.com/en/latest/analyst/DevelopQueries/QueryForms/QueryFormsandParameters.html

In this example the user would enter multiple contract numbers, i.e. 11222, 22333, 33444, 44444, 55555 and all associated contract rows would return.

The issue is that when multiple keywords are entered there are no records returned. A single keyword does return values but I need the multiple keyword search in one form field.

```
select *

From eda.table1

Where contractnumber IN (${contractnumber:type:raw});
```

Answer (score 0):

The user should enter the list as it would appear in SQL IN statements... so they should type:

```
'11222', '22333', '33444', '44444', '55555'
```

Alation will set 'contractnumber' = '11222', '22333', '33444', '44444', '55555'

So the query will run as:

```
select *

From eda.table1

Where contractnumber IN ('11222', '22333', '33444', '44444', '55555');
```